EF Core DbContext always uses the wrong connection string when migrating data between databases
I'm facing an issue with dependency injection in my .NET Core project using Entity Framework Core. I have multiple DbContexts (SourceDbContext and TargetDbContext), both inheriting from ApplicationDbContext. The goal is to migrate data from my development database (source) to my QA database (target), using two distinct connection strings.
However, when I try to print the connection string for SourceDbContext, it always uses the connection string for TargetDbContext (DefaultConnection), instead of using PreviousConnection.
Here is my code - Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
           .AddInterceptors(new PerformanceInterceptor()));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<SourceDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PreviousConnection")));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<TargetDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

DataMigrationService:
public class DataMigrationService
{
    private readonly SourceDbContext _sourceContext;
    private readonly TargetDbContext _targetContext;

    public DataMigrationService(SourceDbContext sourceContext, TargetDbContext targetContext)
    {
        _sourceContext = sourceContext;
        _targetContext = targetContext;
    }

    public async Task MigrateTableDataAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Source DB Connection String: {_sourceContext.Database.GetConnectionString()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Target DB Connection String: {_targetContext.Database.GetConnectionString()}");

        // Fetch data from source DB
        var sourceWhiteLists = await _sourceContext.EmailDomainWhiteLists.ToListAsync();
        
        // Fetch data from target DB
        var targetWhiteLists = await _targetContext.EmailDomainWhiteLists.ToListAsync();
        
        foreach (var wl in sourceWhiteLists)
        {
            var targetWL = await _targetContext.EmailDomainWhiteLists.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Value == wl.Value);
            if (targetWL == null)
            {
                _targetContext.EmailDomainWhiteLists.Add(wl);
            }
        }

        await _targetContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Migration completed.");
    }
}

SourceDbContext:
public class SourceDbContext : ApplicationDbContext
{
    public SourceDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}

In Program.cs, I'm injecting SourceDbContext and TargetDbContext with different connection strings. However, SourceDbContext seems to inherit the connection string from ApplicationDbContext, which always points to the QA database.
How can I ensure that SourceDbContext uses its own connection string (PreviousConnection) rather than inheriting the default one from ApplicationDbContext?
Thanks in advance!
Additional information:

I've tried checking the connection string using Console.WriteLine, and it's clear that SourceDbContext is still using the DefaultConnection
I need both SourceDbContext and TargetDbContext to use their respective connection strings for DEV and QA environments

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

All of your contexts should inherit from DbContext and not ApplicationDbContext.

The issue will likely stem from this constructor:
public SourceDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    : base(options)

A constructor for a SourceDbContext should expect DbContextOptions<SourceDbContext> but in doing so you won't be able to extend a base ApplicationDbContext as that expects options for ApplicationDbContext. Chances are that the DbContextOptions passed are resolved from the default registration for ApplicationDbContext not the SourceDbContext.
If you want to define a base class for application DbContexts for your Source and Target to extend using different options then one option is to make the base ApplicationDbContext generic:
public abstract class ApplicationDbContext<T> : DbContext where T : ApplicationDbContext<T>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<T> options) 
        : base (options) { }

    // ...
}

public class SourceDbContext : ApplicationDbContext<SourceDbContext>
{
    public SourceDbContext(DbContextOptions<SourceDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }
}

... as well as for the TargetDbContext.
This should ensure that your Source/Target DbContexts can resolve the their DbOptions respectively and pass them down through the base ApplicationDbContext.
Note that in this case you do not configure ApplicationDbContext, so the following code gets removed.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
       .AddInterceptors(new PerformanceInterceptor()));

Instead, configure the interceptors on each of the concrete DbContexts as applicable.
